# How to change button text in Reactjs for a few seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I know how to change the text of button (using a component state for example). But how to change the text for a few seconds?

For example: I click button with the text "Save". The request goes on the server and when I get response from the server and there are no mistakes, I need to change the text of the button on "Saved" for 3 seconds and return "Save" then.

Comment: use setTimeout.

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it like so

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ text: "Loading..." });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ text: "Save" });
    }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: Wow it was really that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the state of button text inside timeout.